# Add permission to Lambda in command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I can create API to expose my Lambda functions through the GUI. It works perfectly.

However, I need create API automatically, by CLI. When I create my API from the command line, I get the following error when running the API:

> Execution failed due to configuration error: API Gateway does not have
> permission to assume the provided role

I think that the missing permission is this from photo, that when using the GUI is created automatically.

[image]

How can I create this permission by command line?

Comment: I think you need to give permission to the IAM user that's using the CLI

Comment: @NaguibIhab I have only one IAM user. How to check if user has permission?

Comment: Go to Services and select IAM, go then to users

Comment: @NaguibIhab It's not work. I already have access to that.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that you are creating the function with the correct role policy document:

```
ROLE_ARN=`aws iam create-role --role-name ${ROLE_NAME} --assume-role-policy-document file://trust-relationship-policy-document.json --query "Role.Arn" --output text`
aws lambda create-function --function-name ${API_NAME} --runtime nodejs4.3 --role $ROLE_ARN --handler "index.handler" --zip-file fileb://lambda-package.zip
```

My trust-relationship-policy-document.json would look something like this:

```js
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "lambda.amazonaws.com",
          "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Second, to add the permission in the screenshot that you showed, you need to run something like this:

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name ${FUNCTION_ARN} --action "lambda:InvokeFunction" --statement-id 1 --principal apigateway.amazonaws.com --source-arn "arn:aws:execute-api:"${REGION}":"${ACCOUNT_ID}":"${API_ID}"/*/*/"${API_NAME}
```

The statement ID is just a value that you have to provide for the call to work. For our purposes, we don't need to bother much about it.
This is what I use to deploy my functions, let me know in the comments if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you by reply. I tried, but no work. I get the same error message. I use the `aws lambda add-permission` thus: http://pastebin.com/ht87XKeW